# Can I change the name of a variable depending on another variable?

Tags: python, variables

I want to change a variable using another variable without doing the boring old way of:

```
if choice == 'tuna':
  tuna_num -= 1
```

Instead I wanted to do it in a just as quick way as the method seen below:

```
tuna_num = 1
bacon_num = 1

#important bits v
choice = input('Choose a variable name to edit')
(choice)_num -= 1
print((choice)_num)
```

(Sorry if this is simple or if I'm just being stupid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict:

```
nums = {
    'tuna': 1,
    'bacon': 1,
}

choice = input('Choose a variable name to edit')
nums[choice] -= 1
print(nums[choice])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad thing to do, but:

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> vars()['a'] = 2
>>> print(a)
2
```

So:

```py
tuna_num = 1
bacon_num = 1

#important bits v
choice = input('Choose a variable name to edit')
if f"{choice}_num" in vars():
    vars()[f"{choice}_num"] -= 1
print(vars()[f"{choice}_num"])
```

Comment: Note that this won't work properly in a function; it works fine in global scope, because `vars()` ends up returning the real `dict` globals are stored in, but in a function, it acts like `locals()`, which returns a *copy* of the locals as a `dict`, and mutations to it won't work properly (docs specifically warn against it even in the cases where it works).